# Have renamed and modified file in git. How to make two commits, one for renaming and one for the contents?

Tags: git

I've searched google and stackoverflow for an answer but not found any. Yes I could read the man pages and figure it out for myself, but I think there should be an easily accessible best-practice answer to this question here.

So, say `oldname.py` was renamed `newname.py` and modified, and now I want to first commit the rename operation without committing any of the changed contents, and then commit the changes in a new, separate commit. No changes have been staged.

Comment: I would : 1) rename to the old name. 2) add/commit 3) rename to the new name. 4) add/commit. Note : this is not the order you stated but you may not care about it.

Comment: And remember to `git mv` it before modifying next time.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I wanted the opposite order, yes, but in this specific case doing it the other way is OK. I still want to know the best way to do it in the opposite order though.

Comment: @nitgit In the opposite order, you might be able to do something with `git stash` / `git stash pop` but the renaming might make the `git stash pop` fail. Renaming the file 3 times should do the trick but there is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
# choose some way to "stash" your modifications
# either use git stash (you will need to 'git add' the new files, but not 'git commit' them)
# or simply rename them, e.g : mv newname.py newname.py.keep

$ git checkout oldname.py
$ git mv oldname.py newname.py
$ git commit

# get back your "stashed" content
# either 'git stash pop', and solve conflicts
# or rename the files to their target name, e.g : mv newname.py.keep newname.py

$ git add newname.py
$ git commit
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll get back to this answer and upvote it when I have enough reputation. :-)

Comment: @nitgit you should accept the answer regardless, if it solved your problem. Accepting an answer doesn't need reputation. See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)